# Why is @Sql not working within Spring test?

Tags: java, testing, spring-data-jpa

I have a `@DataJpaTest` which requires some database intialization. I have tried putting a `data.sql` within the resources folder and it works. However, I would like to initialize the database with data specific for this test.

It seems, `@Sql` is the preferred way to do so. However, in my case it is not working, although the specified file is located within resources. The database simply isn't initialized.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@Sql` annotation is processed by the `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`. Without this listener, there will be no evaluation of the `@Sql` annotation. While this listener is registered in a standard `@DataJpaTest`, the semantics change, if you explicitly specify further listeners explicitly.

In the relevant test, I had registered a custom listener and as the `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener` was not explicitly mentioned alongside the other listener, it was not added by spring. Commenting out the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation lead to using the sql-file as did adding the `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`.